# Output of Point Cloud Cropping using PDAL displaying as straight line

Tags: clip, las, point-cloud, pdal, laz

I am cropping my point cloud (.las) using PDAL, when i display my original point cloud it looks like this,

[image]

But after i crop it, the output looks like this, i.e. a straight line in viewer mode.

[image]

Here is the pipeline script that i am using to crop it.

```
{
"pipeline": [
    {
        "type": "readers.las",
        "filename": "/Users/ahsanmukhtar/Downloads/merged.las"
    },
    {
        "type": "filters.crop",
        "polygon": "Polygon ((-71.11600113658539613 42.32834169613819597, -71.1155733718496208 42.33223046646342169, -71.11265679410570328 42.33487483028457632, -71.11623446280489702 42.33888026371955249, -71.11518449481708615 42.34199127997973022, -71.11117906138211708 42.34311902337405087, -71.10351818384141609 42.34315791107729865, -71.10332374532515587 42.32989720426828484, -71.11600113658539613 42.32834169613819597))",
        "outside": false
    },
    {
        "type": "writers.las",
        "filename": "/Users/ahsanmukhtar/Downloads/mergedoutput.las",
       "a_srs": "EPSG:6318",
        "extra_dims": "GpsTime=float,PointSourceId=uint16,UserData=uint8,Classification=uint8,ScanAngleRank=int8,PointSourceId=uint16,NumberOfReturns=uint8,ReturnNumber=uint8,Intensity=uint16"

    }
] }
```

Orignal .las file pdal info

```
  {
  "file_size": 528529479,
  "filename": "merged.las",
  "now": "2023-03-14T12:42:42+0500",
  "pdal_version": "2.4.3 (git-version: Release)",
  "reader": "readers.las",
  "stats":
  {
    "bbox":
    {
      "EPSG:4326":
      {
        "bbox":
        {
          "maxx": -71.099454,
          "maxy": 42.34753,
          "maxz": 115.68,
          "minx": -71.1185487,
          "miny": 42.3201975,
          "minz": -37.31
        },
        "boundary": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -71.1185487, 42.3201975, -37.31 ], [ -71.1185487, 42.34753, -37.31 ], [ -71.099454, 42.34753, 115.68 ], [ -71.099454, 42.3201975, 115.68 ], [ -71.1185487, 42.3201975, -37.31 ] ] ] }
      },
      "native":
      {
        "bbox":
        {
          "maxx": -71.099454,
          "maxy": 42.34753,
          "maxz": 115.68,
          "minx": -71.1185487,
          "miny": 42.3201975,
          "minz": -37.31
        },
        "boundary": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -71.1185487, 42.3201975, -37.31 ], [ -71.1185487, 42.34753, -37.31 ], [ -71.099454, 42.34753, 115.68 ], [ -71.099454, 42.3201975, 115.68 ], [ -71.1185487, 42.3201975, -37.31 ] ] ] }
      }
    },
    "statistic":
    [
      {
        "average": -71.10972695,
        "count": 18876041,
        "maximum": -71.099454,
        "minimum": -71.1185487,
        "name": "X",
        "position": 0,
        "stddev": 0.005159778384,
        "variance": 2.662331298e-05
      },
      {
        "average": 42.33383385,
        "count": 18876041,
        "maximum": 42.34753,
        "minimum": 42.3201975,
        "name": "Y",
        "position": 1,
        "stddev": 0.00789192229,
        "variance": 6.228243743e-05
      },
      {
        "average": 20.27862693,
        "count": 18876041,
        "maximum": 115.68,
        "minimum": -37.31,
        "name": "Z",
        "position": 2,
        "stddev": 15.43676484,
        "variance": 238.2937086
      },
      {
        "average": 124.6419345,
        "count": 18876041,
        "maximum": 255,
        "minimum": 0,
        "name": "Intensity",
        "position": 3,
        "stddev": 81.10823213,
        "variance": 6578.545319
      },
      {
        "average": 1.230568423,
        "count": 18876041,
        "maximum": 5,
        "minimum": 1,
        "name": "ReturnNumber",
        "position": 4,
        "stddev": 0.4997657185,
        "variance": 0.2497657734
      },
      {
        "average": 1.461075127,
        "count": 18876041,
        "maximum": 5,
        "minimum": 1,
        "name": "NumberOfReturns",
        "position": 5,
        "stddev": 0.6822574218,
        "variance": 0.4654751895
      },
      {
        "average": 0.4936215174,
        "count": 18876041,
        "maximum": 1,
        "minimum": 0,
        "name": "ScanDirectionFlag",
        "position": 6,
        "stddev": 0.4999593265,
        "variance": 0.2499593282
      },
      {
        "average": 0.0006216345896,
        "count": 18876041,
        "maximum": 1,
        "minimum": 0,
        "name": "EdgeOfFlightLine",
        "position": 7,
        "stddev": 0.02492485091,
        "variance": 0.0006212481929
      },
      {
        "average": 7.049663168,
        "count": 18876041,
        "maximum": 18,
        "minimum": 1,
        "name": "Classification",
        "position": 8,
        "stddev": 7.642884811,
        "variance": 58.41368823
      },
      {
        "average": -4.154081886,
        "count": 18876041,
        "maximum": 20,
        "minimum": -22,
        "name": "ScanAngleRank",
        "position": 9,
        "stddev": 11.64908234,
        "variance": 135.7011194
      },
      {
        "average": 0,
        "count": 18876041,
        "maximum": 0,
        "minimum": 0,
        "name": "UserData",
        "position": 10,
        "stddev": 0,
        "variance": 0
      },
      {
        "average": 1121.200477,
        "count": 18876041,
        "maximum": 1122,
        "minimum": 1120,
        "name": "PointSourceId",
        "position": 11,
        "stddev": 0.6546073365,
        "variance": 0.4285107651
      },
      {
        "average": 70556164.11,
        "count": 18876041,
        "maximum": 70556943.42,
        "minimum": 70555524.72,
        "name": "GpsTime",
        "position": 12,
        "stddev": 476.4291702,
        "variance": 226984.7542
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Output point cloud .las pdal info

```
{
  "file_size": 293826452,
  "filename": "mergedoutput.las",
  "now": "2023-03-14T12:44:18+0500",
  "pdal_version": "2.4.3 (git-version: Release)",
  "reader": "readers.las",
  "stats":
  {
    "bbox":
    {
      "EPSG:4326":
      {
        "bbox":
        {
          "maxx": -71.1,
          "maxy": 42.34,
          "maxz": 115.68,
          "minx": -71.12,
          "miny": 42.33,
          "minz": -37.31
        },
        "boundary": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -71.12, 42.33, -37.31 ], [ -71.12, 42.34, -37.31 ], [ -71.1, 42.34, 115.68 ], [ -71.1, 42.33, 115.68 ], [ -71.12, 42.33, -37.31 ] ] ] }
      },
      "native":
      {
        "bbox":
        {
          "maxx": -71.1,
          "maxy": 42.34,
          "maxz": 115.68,
          "minx": -71.12,
          "miny": 42.33,
          "minz": -37.31
        },
        "boundary": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -71.12, 42.33, -37.31 ], [ -71.12, 42.34, -37.31 ], [ -71.1, 42.34, 115.68 ], [ -71.1, 42.33, 115.68 ], [ -71.12, 42.33, -37.31 ] ] ] }
      }
    },
    "statistic":
    [
      {
        "average": -71.10898077,
        "count": 5996412,
        "maximum": -71.1,
        "minimum": -71.12,
        "name": "X",
        "position": 0,
        "stddev": 0.004390237066,
        "variance": 1.927418149e-05
      },
      {
        "average": 42.33593221,
        "count": 5996412,
        "maximum": 42.34,
        "minimum": 42.33,
        "name": "Y",
        "position": 1,
        "stddev": 0.004912330738,
        "variance": 2.413099328e-05
      },
      {
        "average": 20.86181769,
        "count": 5996412,
        "maximum": 115.68,
        "minimum": -37.31,
        "name": "Z",
        "position": 2,
        "stddev": 17.88719979,
        "variance": 319.9519162
      },
      {
        "average": 126.2783359,
        "count": 5996412,
        "maximum": 255,
        "minimum": 0,
        "name": "Intensity",
        "position": 3,
        "stddev": 80.27592736,
        "variance": 6444.224514
      },
      {
        "average": 1.20089797,
        "count": 5996412,
        "maximum": 5,
        "minimum": 1,
        "name": "ReturnNumber",
        "position": 4,
        "stddev": 0.46887078,
        "variance": 0.2198398083
      },
      {
        "average": 1.400862382,
        "count": 5996412,
        "maximum": 5,
        "minimum": 1,
        "name": "NumberOfReturns",
        "position": 5,
        "stddev": 0.6459091766,
        "variance": 0.4171986644
      },
      {
        "average": 0.4852553494,
        "count": 5996412,
        "maximum": 1,
        "minimum": 0,
        "name": "ScanDirectionFlag",
        "position": 6,
        "stddev": 0.4997825897,
        "variance": 0.2497826369
      },
      {
        "average": 0.0007382748217,
        "count": 5996412,
        "maximum": 1,
        "minimum": 0,
        "name": "EdgeOfFlightLine",
        "position": 7,
        "stddev": 0.02716118361,
        "variance": 0.000737729895
      },
      {
        "average": 7.080619044,
        "count": 5996412,
        "maximum": 18,
        "minimum": 1,
        "name": "Classification",
        "position": 8,
        "stddev": 7.648722255,
        "variance": 58.50295214
      },
      {
        "average": -9.849869222,
        "count": 5996412,
        "maximum": 19,
        "minimum": -22,
        "name": "ScanAngleRank",
        "position": 9,
        "stddev": 8.554130657,
        "variance": 73.1731513
      },
      {
        "average": 0,
        "count": 5996412,
        "maximum": 0,
        "minimum": 0,
        "name": "UserData",
        "position": 10,
        "stddev": 0,
        "variance": 0
      },
      {
        "average": 1121.309626,
        "count": 5996412,
        "maximum": 1122,
        "minimum": 1120,
        "name": "PointSourceId",
        "position": 11,
        "stddev": 0.508023765,
        "variance": 0.2580881458
      },
      {
        "average": 0,
        "count": 5996412,
        "maximum": 0,
        "minimum": 0,
        "name": "Red",
        "position": 12,
        "stddev": 0,
        "variance": 0
      },
      {
        "average": 0,
        "count": 5996412,
        "maximum": 0,
        "minimum": 0,
        "name": "Green",
        "position": 13,
        "stddev": 0,
        "variance": 0
      },
      {
        "average": 0,
        "count": 5996412,
        "maximum": 0,
        "minimum": 0,
        "name": "Blue",
        "position": 14,
        "stddev": 0,
        "variance": 0
      },
      {
        "average": 70556102.9,
        "count": 5996412,
        "maximum": 70556934.56,
        "minimum": 70555538.3,
        "name": "GpsTime",
        "position": 15,
        "stddev": 399.499486,
        "variance": 159599.8393
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

My boundary and initial point cloud are in EPSG::6318 coordinate system, and have checked the output EPSG as well, it's in 6318.

Why i am getting the view of output cropped point cloud like this?

PDAL Version: 2.4.3
Original LAS File: [Download Link](https://we.tl/t-EgsjsMfXR4?utm_campaign=TRN_TDL_05&utm_source=sendgrid&utm_medium=email&trk=TRN_TDL_05)

For Visualization i am using [LIDAR VIEW](http://lidarview.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure to set your scale on `writers.las`

```
{
    "type" : "writers.las",
    "scale_x":"0.0000001",
    "scale_y":"0.0000001",
    "scale_z":"0.01",
    "offset_x":"auto",
    "offset_y":"auto",
    "offset_z":"auto",
    "filename" : "output.las"
}
```

See https://pdal.io/en/2.5.2/tutorial/las.html#auto-offset-example for specifics.